# Why Doesn't My Program Work Correctly

Tags: c++

My program needs to parse a csv file and identify a missing combination of numbers. Order doesn't matter.

The program compiles and runs, but prints out numbers that are already printed in a line in the file.

**Input (mega2.csv):**

```
123
134
142
```

*Note `234` isn't in the list.*

**Expected output:**
The program is supposed to output `234` since it's the only combination not used. Instead nothing outputs.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 

    ifstream inFile; 
    string value;
    string fileName;
    int count;
    int amount, playCount;
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l;
    srand(time(0));
    char ch;


do{

    cout << "Enter number of plays (or -number to quit): ";

    cin >> amount;

    cout << endl;

    playCount = 1;

    while( playCount <= amount ){

        do{

            inFile.open("mega2.csv");

            //create random numbers a,b,c,d,e,f= mega num < 10

            a = rand() % 5;

            if(a == 0){a = 1;}

            do{
            b = rand() % 5;

            if(b == 0){b = 1;}
            }while(b == a);

            do{
            c = rand() % 5;

            if(c == 0){c = 1;}
            }while(c == a || c == b);




            //Load numbers into g,h,i,j,k,l

            do{


            inFile >> g;
            inFile.get(ch);
            inFile >> h;
            inFile.get(ch);
            inFile >> i;
            inFile.get(ch);

        int count = 0;

        cout << g << "," << h << "," << i << endl;



    //A     
    if( a == g || a == h || a == i ){

        count++;
    }

    //B 
    if( b == g || b == h || b == i ){

        count++;
    }

    //C 
    if( c == g || c == h || c == i ){

        count++;
    }



}// close second half do loop

    while(inFile && count < 3);

    inFile.close();
    inFile.clear();


} // close whole do loop

    while(count >= 3);

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << endl;

    cout << endl;

    playCount++;

} // End playCount while loop

}// End main do loop

while(amount >= 0); // quit program with negative number

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to have a more descriptive title and remove the parts of the code that are irrelevant. Before posting you should run the exact code you post and make sure that the problem occurs in it.

Comment: "There are some unnecessary things in the code. They don't affect anything. Just ignore them." How about you remove the irrelevant parts and provide us with a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)? This would make it easier for the StackOverflow community to help you. See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: As a general point, consider indenting your code more conventionally. While the compiler (and your IDE, assuming you're using one of those) doesn't need it, it makes it much easier for _you_ to read the code and figure out what bit goes with what. If that makes you think your code is going too deep, you're absolutely right but the problem then is that it _is too deeply indented_ and should be refactored into multiple functions. Do this to make your code make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int count;
```

in the `main()` is never initialized so it contains Indeterminate value.
Initialize it first:

```
int count = 0;
```

**EDIT:**
For those late to the party or for those who downvoted in haste without bothering to actually read the code:

There are two `count` variables being used here. One in scope of `main()` and another inside the `do-while` loop. The `count` inside the loop is initialized but the `count` in `main()` is not and that is the one that gets used in the condition of `do-while`.

Here is a **[small snippet](http://ideone.com/ktmBu)** which demonstrates what I am talking about if anyone still has troubles understanding this.

Comment: @ShashankKadne: Unless my eyes are betraying me, the `count` being used in `do-while` is the one declared in scope of `main()` and that is never initialized.

Comment: I can see int count=0 inside his do-while

Comment: @ShashankKadne; `count` declared inside the `do-while` is not being used in the while condition of `do-while`. The `count` declared in `main()` is the one that gets used. [This](http://ideone.com/ktmBu) helps you understand hopefully.

Comment: And given the above I would love to see some clarification for Downvotes.

Comment: This is certainly one of the problems.

Comment: @Als: Hmm...i didn't notice that count is also being used outside the loop...sorry my mistake....i take my downvote back and (+1) for your close observation.....

Comment: I am unable to upvote unless you edit your answer...please edit your answer so that people would know which "count" you are referring too...

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm for detecting the missing combination using `rand()` looks deeply suspicious. But I guess this is some kind of exercise, so I'll leave you to figure this out for yourself.

Some issue that you need to address with your code which will lead to confusing behaviour like you are seeing.

- Only one of your variables is initialised. They should **all** be initialised, like this:

  ```
  string fileName = "mega2.csv";
  ```
- You have two variables called `count`. You should rename them (and other badly-named variables). What are they counting?
- You don't check whether the file was opened successful and act appropriately if it is not:

  ```
          if (!inFile)
          {
              std::cerr << "Could not open file [" << fileName << "]. Exiting." << std::endl;
              break;
          }
  ```
- You don't check whether the variables were read in from file successfully and act appropriately if they are not. Given you're trying to read three comma-separated values from your file but your input file doesn't contain any commas, this is likely to be a problem!
- You do not validate the user input.

  ```
  cout << "Enter number of plays (or -number to quit): ";
  if (!(cin >> amount))
  {
      std::cerr << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
      break;
  }
  ```
- You have unused variables. Remove these.

Additionally, your `main()` is doing much too much. Try breaking your code down into much, much smaller components. This will make it easier for you to test and for others to read.